# Intersect polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon, intersection, union

I have the following situation: two layers that I want to intersect. The first layer has polygons over agricultural areas (blue polygons). The second one is the Study area (green polygon). I want to use the "Study area" layer to complete the blank spaces of the first one:

I am trying with intersect but it is not working.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Edit to reply the answer

I have tried your option but I don't have the expected results. Both layers have the same projection[image]

[image]

---

Second edit:

[image]

Comment: Check the geometry of the field polygon layers. You may have invalid geometries. You can do that using 'Vector -> Geometry tool -> Check Geometries'

Comment: It seems I have both invalid and error output. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: That is another question, and it is difficult to answer it here without knowing what type of invalid geometry do you have. I think it is better to ask another question describing the type of invalid geometry: overlapping polygons, self-intersection, etc. Make it clear to attract more answers. For this question, the solution is using union with valid geometry.

Comment: Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue you may use "**Union**"

Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Union.

This Link describe better - http://grindgis.com/software/qgis/basic-editing-tools-in-qgis

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I just edit the question to show my problem. I am doing the same as you but the output is not correct

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Union tool from Vector -> Geoprocessing tools -> Union.

[image]

Make sure that both layers should have the same projection to work properly. Otherwise, you may have undesirable results.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I just edit the question to show my problem. I am doing the same as you but the output is not correct